# Separating list with coordinates in two different coordinate systems using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, excel

I have an excel list with approximately 10.000 poles which I want to export to a Point layer to view in ArcMap. However, the coordinates are a mix between SWEREF99 and RT90 and I am not sure how to know which of the poles are in which coordinate system.

Is there anyway to know which coordinate system is which? Or is it possible to create the Point layer and correct it in ArcMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RT90 have 7 digits in x coordinate, SWEREF only 6. So:

1. Sort by x coordinate, split into two excel files.
2. Add excel files to ArcMap
3. Create two point layers using [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm)
4. [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) RT90 points into Sweref
5. Merge points into one sweref point feature class